# How to check whether the user is login or not in freshmembership?

Tags: twig

I want simple "if" "else" condition logic for user log in and log out using freshmembership.com.The technology used here is TWIG TECHNOLOGY.

Comment: Please refer [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: which thing in question that you are not able understand ? i just need a code where i can check user is login or not in freshmember.com..

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: if i know how to get login user than why should i ask this question .. are you aware of freshmember.com.. in that i don't no how to get user is login or not..

Comment: Please refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: please check the answer .. :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

{% if session.userdata.user_id = 0 %}

## user is not login

{% else %}

## user is login

{% endif %}